# How can I make the first entry in a glossary bold?

Tags: math-mode, glossaries, bold

I like to make the first entry bold. However, my approach is not working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{$\mathbf{#1}$}}%\mathbf only for testing->not working

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{term1}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{A_1}}}{test}
\newacronym{term2}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{A_2}}}{test}

\begin{document}

    \gls{term1}
    \gls{term2}
    
    %This is not working for the first glossary entry
    \textbf{$\mathbf{\ensuremath{A_1}}$}

    \printglossary[type=acronym, nonumberlist, title={List of Acronyms}]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want A1 and A2 in bold? Why you didn't define them as `\newacronym{term1}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\mathbf{A_1}}}}{test}`?

Comment: As I only want to have them in the glossary in bold. Text usage should not be bold

Comment: IMHO, it is strange to have acronym in math mode. It most likely should be those initial letters of some phrase (e.g. UFO means “Unidentified Flying Object”). Do you want define a symbol list or acronym list. If you really need A1 as a acronym you can use `\newacronym{term1}{A\textsubscript{1}}{test}` in the definition.

Comment: From my understanding acronym is just a predefined glossary with some predefined functions. Thus it should make no difference to use a symbol list instead. I can change that but the result stays the same. In case I delete the \ensuremath in the \newentry command, I need an alternative for math text there (I call glossary entries in the glossary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your use case. I hope this is what you expect. As I mentioned in the comment. The default `list` glossary style will make the first entry in glossary with bold font and normal usage in normal font. But if you put the entry in math mode, it won't be bold. Instead, you could set the `name` key in optional arguments for `\newacronym`, such as `\newacronym[name=\ensuremath{\mathrm{\mathbf{A_1}}}]{term1}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{A_1}}}{test}`. You also mentioned you want to call glossary entries in the glossary. This will mess up the output as well. I recommend you don't do that. I will include an example for this nested call as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[name=\ensuremath{\mathbf{A_1}}]{term1}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{A_1}}}{test}
\newacronym[name=\ensuremath{\mathbf{A_2}}]{term2}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{A_2}}}{test is showed in \ensuremath{\mathrm{A_1}}}
%\newacronym[name=\ensuremath{\mathbf{A_2}}]{term2}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{A_2}}}{test is showed in \gls{term1}} % If you try this definition, you will see the output will be messed up.

\begin{document}
This is use of acronym ``\gls{term1}", this is another use of acronym ``\gls{term2}". 

\printglossary[type=acronym, nonumberlist, title={List of Acronyms}]
\end{document}
```

> Output:

[image]

Comment: That might work although I prefer a solution where I do not have to change all of my glossary entries. Is there anywhere easy to find documented or does somebody know where the name attributed is used visually? If it is only used in the printed glossary then it is fine. Then I will change all of my name attributes and add the text attribute.

Comment: @Thomas I think if the `text` attribute didn't defined. `name` will also be used for normal  usage in document (e.g.  '\gls' command). But in acronym, the `text` was defined according to short and long form in the last two args, so name will be used in the printed glossary only. I am not too sure. You could check the official document on ctan (P.129): https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I have tested it as an easy example. I will give it a try for my whole document now. Probably it will work but some changes are required